# PivotTable reports that are set to refresh when the item in a report filter changes

Tags: excel, sharepoint, parameters

I want to show an excel with a parameter in it's query. But xlviewer show this error : We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:

• PivotTable reports that are set to refresh when the item in a report filter changes, or external data ranges (also called query tables) that use parameters
Do you want to open the file in Excel instead?

[image]

My query in excel is like this :
[image]

I need to load data into workbook by query string parameter.

Answer (score -1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/sharepoint-server-help/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-HA104009811.aspx

View this link, I have also kenna have the same problem trying to figure it out

Comment: Can you bring (at least the gist of) the relevant content into the answer to make it future-proof against dead links. Thanks